# Dotnet core issue

Tags: .net-core, project

I have faced with a problem in my dotnet api project .
I have project.csproj file but still this error while dotnet run command.
Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure the project exists in  path.

I build the project via (dotne new project -o Myproject -n Myproject )
Command I don't know what is wrong please help me out of the problem.

Comment: are you using visual studio? or just the cmd line?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add Template and lang
**(Template options)**
check this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).